# Xpath query to get value based on a different path's value (if, then...)

Tags: xml, xpath, import

Completely new to xpath here. Go easy on me.

I'm using wp-property import and I was able to succesfully connect to the RETS server and download the properties. However, two vital piece of info for each property are found in other paths and were not downloaded: the office name and the agent name.

I've received everything from the Property path I've needed except for these two elements. In each property, there is a [ListingOfficeID].  The [listor_name] is blank (sadly).

Property (name)
Property (class)
ListingID (ID) 
[ListingOfficeID] (attribute) 
[listor_name] (blank attribute)

I have to link the [ListingOfficeID] to the correct [OfficeID] in the Office node and pull its corresponding [account] which is the name.

Office (name)
Office (class)
ListingOfficeID (ID)
[OfficeID] (attribute)
[account] (attribute)

In wp-property import, the xpath rules for each attribute is simple. You don't the brackets. But I'm pulling from one node only. So, I'm trying to come up with a path to match the office IDs and pull the account value.

[attribute xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCjZR.jpg)

I've tried:

listor_name = //Office/Office/[ListingOfficeID=OfficeID]/account

//Office/Office/ListingOfficeID/ [//Property/Property/ListingID/[ListingOfficeID]/[account]

//Office/Office/[@ListingOfficeID= //Property/Property/ListingID/[ListingOfficeID]]/[account]

/Office/Office/ListingOfficeID = [@[/Property/Property/ListingID/[@ListingOfficeID]]]/[@account]

But these are not working.

This is a sample of the property XML:

[property xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dDWs.jpg)

And I need the [ListingOfficeID] to be matched to the [OfficeID] in the Office XML to pull the respective [account]:

[office xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZvBw.jpg)

Here is the raw XML from the property table:
[Raw XML Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRq42.jpg)

Showing the [ListingOfficeID] that needs to be matched to the [OfficeID] of the Office table, to pull the [account] - here is the office raw XML.

[raw xml office](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NHiC.jpg)

This is what I think should work but does not:
/Office/Office[@OfficeID="/Property/Property/ListingOfficeID"]/account

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and post a representative sample of the xml. It's impossible to answer the question without it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Hope this addition helps.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't help. You should post a representative sample of the actual raw xml, not an image. You can't test xpath expressions (or anything else, for that matter) on an image...

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I can't post the URL. It is password AND IP protected, which makes things more difficult.